# Vibrator does not vibrate after power button is pressed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a service which is calling the vibrator.

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public MyService()
    {
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer( getCurrentPendingObjects, null, 100, Timeout.Infinite );

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override bool OnUnbind( Intent intent )
    {
        return base.OnUnbind( intent );
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {           
        binder = new MyServiceBinder( this );

        return binder;
    }   

    private void getCurrentPendingObjects( Object state )
    {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.GetSystemService( Context.VibratorService );

        long [] vibrationPatern = new long[ ] { 100, 170 };
         vibrator.Vibrate( vibrationPatern, 1 );
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I press the power button causing the screen to turn off, and device to enter in sleep mode.
The service seems like continue working, but the vibrator stop vibrating.

- How to keep vibrator vibrating even the device entered in sleep mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm seems like an interesting app you are making... :P

I think to keep the service running you will need a `WakeLock` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.PowerManager+WakeLock/

> A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on.
>
> Any application using a WakeLock must request the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission in an  element of the application's manifest. Obtain a wake lock by calling PowerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags,String).
>
> Call PowerManager+WakeLock.Acquire to acquire the wake lock and force the device to stay on at the level that was requested when the wake lock was created.
>
> Call PowerManager+WakeLock.Release when you are done and don't need the lock anymore. It is very important to do this as soon as possible to avoid running down the device's battery excessively.

You might be able to do this:

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    
    private PowerManager _powerManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock _wakeLock;

    public MyService()
    {
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
         _powerManager = (PowerManager) GetSystemService(PowerService);
        _wakeLock = _powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags. Partial, "Vibrator");
        _wakeLock.Acquire();

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer( getCurrentPendingObjects, null, 100, Timeout.Infinite );

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override bool OnUnbind( Intent intent )
    {
         if (_wakeLock.IsHeld)
            _wakeLock.Release();
        return base.OnUnbind( intent );
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {           
        binder = new MyServiceBinder( this );

        return binder;
    }   

    private void getCurrentPendingObjects( Object state )
    {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.GetSystemService( Context.VibratorService );

        long [] vibrationPatern = new long[ ] { 100, 170 };
         vibrator.Vibrate( vibrationPatern, 1 );
    }
}
```

Also you will need this permission in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And release it when you are done like so:

```
if (_wakeLock.IsHeld)
      _wakeLock.Release();
```

Comment: I've just did Your proposal Iain Smith, but once I press the power button the vibrator never call again, even after the screen is woken up by the service.

Comment: Just update my code forgot to create the _powerManager and _wakeLock

Comment: It's reproduced as it is, but once I press the power button and the screen turn off - the vibration stop working.

Comment: one more thing - if the _powerManager = (PowerManager) GetSystemService(PowerService); is inside the service class constructor it is crashing, so i've changed it to StartCommandResult method.

Answer (score 2):

`Wake locks` will keep the system alive, something like:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Application.PowerService);
Android.OS.PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "StackOverFlow");
wakeLock.Acquire();
```

Note: After you are done, release the lock as this will decrease the battery life:

```
wakeLock.Release();
```

Note: Manifest required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Android Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use a BroadcastReceiver you can connect to Screen Off Action. There I could start the Service as follow which works on my device.

```
public class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals(Intent.ActionScreenOff))
        {
             Application.Context.StartService(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MyService)));
        }
    }
}
```

Just register the receiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionScreenOff);
RegisterReceiver(new MyReceiver(), filter);
```

Comment: The service start in the boot of the device, and with it's caring application.
The service is working fine I believe.

Comment: Maybe you have more code. On my device it's vibrating in on and off mode.